# How do I find links with images in Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am trying in Mechanize to follow a link which has a generic image inside. The HTML code looks like this:

```
<a href="something">Next<img src="genericImage"/></a>
```

I would like to find the link by the text, and tried to do this:

```
agent.page.link_with(:text => /Next/)
```

It always returns nil. Is there another way to do some kind of `start_with?("Next")`?

Comment: will this method work - http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-image_with?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since the image url is used multiple places for other links, and there are no alts.

Comment: link_with will return a link or nil, not 'zero results'.

Comment: @Dofs - in the case you describe, mechanize would return the correct link. Maybe you should start a new question and include the url.